# Nginx proxy pass EKS cluster

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have a react app deployed in ingress-nginx service. My react app is wrapped in nginx with the following configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;

  gzip on;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend-app:80;
  }
}
```

I am using the proxy pass to connect to my backend as it does require this according to setup. My ingress setup is as follow

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/http2-push-preload: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-owasp-core-rules: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.co
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: example-app
              servicePort: 80
    - host: "*.example.co"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: example-app
              servicePort: 80
    - host: api.example.co
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: backend-app
              servicePort: 80
```

My backend-app is reachable, however, but my react app Nginx cannot proxy pass to the backend… This does work in minikube but not working in eks

Comment: What is this upstream `proxy_pass http://backend-app:80;`? You need to specify backend-app in nginx config. Also, if backend-app is running on port 80 then you need not put it in a verbose manner.

Comment: The `proxy_pass http://backend-app:80;` is in a deployed app in Kubernetes service.  Also, it doesn't work even if I don't specify the port explicitly

Comment: The idea is I necessarily don't need to specify the public URL of the backend-app as nginx can map it to app in the cluster

Comment: Where is definition of backend-app in nginx config?

Comment: I don't get the question really

Comment: nginx cannot resolve backend-app just like that. You have to define it or make it resolvable.

Comment: You mean like an upstream server

Comment: Yes, like an upstream server. If nginx cannot resolve the nam backend-app it will fail to do a proxy-pass. Check your logs.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know, I think since I am using Kubernetes, the `backend-app` would have been available, if I were to specify an upstream_server, in that case, I would have to specify the backend url which is not so different from `proxy_pass http://api.example.co;`

Comment: What does error logs say?

Comment: The error was returning 499

Comment: 499 is a client error. Can you please paste the error logs of nginx server?

Comment: I am just guessing from config. Try making that api.example.co

Comment: Yes it works if I do that actually... but I was wondering  why it works in minikube with the initial configuration

Comment: http://<domain> is a name to be resolved. Another name people use for this is host(a bad name). I have no experience with minicube. Most probably it is adding an entry for ServiceName to be resolved.